# How to convert array to string, suitable for JSON.stringify

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have an array in the database and it looks like this: `{"hello":"world", "Test":["hello"]}`, which is perfect for `JSON.stringify`, but when I select it from the database like this:

```
$metadata = $this->repository->getMetadata($id);

$data = json_encode($metadata);

return $this->render('AcmeQuotesBundle:Home:metadata.html.twig', array('data' => $data));
```

and put this in the template:

```
{% block body %}
    <script>
        var obj = {{ data|raw }}

        document.body.innerHTML = "";
        document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4)));
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

I get this output:

```
[
    {
        "quoteMetadata": "{\"hello\":\"world\", \"Test\":[\"hello\"]}"
    }
]
```

which is not what I want. All I want is the value of `obj` to be the native string - `{"hello":"world", "Test":["hello"]}` without `"quoteMetadata":`, without the quotation marks and without the `"\"` around the words. I tried using `implode()`, but I get notice:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs...
```

I'm using Symfony2, Twig and Doctrine2 and I'm doing all this because I want the string from the database  to be shown in a easy for reading way like here - http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/HZPVL/ If you have any ideas how to fix this or how to make it in another way, plase share!

---

**EDIT**

When I put `var_dump($matadata)` after `$metadata = $this->repository->getMetadata($id);`, I get this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["quoteMetadata"]=> string(35) "{"hello":"world", "Test":["hello"]}" } }
```

Comment: It looks like you're `json_encode`-ing something that's already `json_encoded`. Can you do a `var_dump($quoteMetadata);` after the first line and show us what it looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your metadata array isn't clean; the bit you want is buried in an associative array inside a single-row array. So try:

```
$metadata = $this->repository->getMetadata($id);
return $this->render('AcmeQuotesBundle:Home:metadata.html.twig', array('data' => $metadata[0]['quoteMetadata']));
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much! I haven't thought of that! It works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Your data isn't perfect for `JSON.stringigy`, it's perfect for `JSON.parse`, which turns the string into an object. Just drop the `JSON.stringify` if you want to output the raw string, or `JSON.parse` it if you want to use the data as an obejct.